# Laravel 5.7 - forget or except from collection when key could vary

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

Laravel's `except()` and `forget()` helpers both do what they do by key. I'm wondering if there's a slick laravel way to use either of those to exclude an item when the key is unpredictable. I have a collection that looks like this:

```
Collection {#469
#items: array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Bug"
    "class" => "App\Models\BugTypes\Bug"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "name" => "PreBug"
    "class" => "App\Models\BugTypes\PreBug"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Request"
    "class" => "App\Models\BugTypes\Request"
  ]
]
}
```

and I want to always exclude `PreBug`. The issue is that the collection is built dynamically from namespaces and if you were to add or remove a namespace, the key for PreBug could change. Namely if you were to create a type that alphabetically precedes the letter P. So while `$data->except(1);` works now, I cannot rely on it. I know I could filter or map to remove it, so mostly just wondering if someone sees a more creative solution than that.

Comment: Why don't you just use filter or map?

Comment: That's my fallback. I was just curious if someone knew of a better way to do it.